# How should I proceed when the recruiter I was working with was laid off?

Tags: job-search, job-offer

I interviewed at a company months ago after being contacted by a recruiter for an open position. I worked with this same recruiter throughout the interview process. They stated up front that they didn't have a specific team for me, but I agreed to the interview anyway to see how it would play out. At the end of the process, they stated that the company really liked me and wanted to extend an offer, but they were unable to do so at the time due to lack of head count. I agreed with the recruiter that I'd stay in touch.

About a month later, I pinged the recruiter for an update, and was told they still didn't have headcount but to stay in touch. I repeated this process once more and got the same response.

Eventually, the recruiter stopped responding to my email communications entirely. My initial assumption was that I was being ghosted, but I only recently discovered via LinkedIn that this recruiter was part of layoffs at the company.

Now it has been about 7 months since I did my first round of interviews. I am considering reaching out to another recruiter at the company, but I'm not sure if this would be viewed as unprofessional. I also see recent layoffs as a signal that they probably won't be hiring anytime soon.

Would reaching out to someone at the company be appropriate in this situation or should I just let this one go?

Comment: Yes, reach out.

Comment: Personally, I'd let it go and move on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The laid off recruiter would have transferred any open requirements/candidates to their replacement. If the company was interested, they should have contacted you by now. Since they haven't, it is fairly likely that either the position you were being hired for went away at the time the layoffs occurred, or they decided to look at other candidates rather than you.

It can't hurt to contact them and ask, and perhaps to ask if there are other positions now open that you should be applying for. But it isn't very likely to help either.

Just continue job searching. Which presumably you have been doing anyway, since you should be interviewing until the day you have a signed document in your hands with start date and salary. (Some would say until your actual first day of work, since things *do* sometimes fall through at last minute. I prefer to not be quite that paranoid.)

Comment: Keep in mind the chances that a company that is laying off recruiters, is actually hiring, is very small. As this answer suggests, if they were interested, you would have already been contacted. It costs nothing to reach out, but personally, I would just move on.